# Removing last character from pandas series only where it has a value

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and Python.

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
A           B
15.00%      21.1564
            21.1564
            21.1564
16.00%      1.1564
```

I am trying to get the differences between `B` and `A`

```
df_final['A'] = float(df_final['A'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1]))
df_final['Difference vs category'] = float(df_final.B)-float(df_final.A)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
df_final['A'] = float(df_final['A'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

As I understand its because there are empty cells in `A` column.

How could I only apply the difference calculation for rows where both `A` and `B` values are present?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast values in pandas by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df_final['A'] = df_final['A'].str[:-1].astype(float)
```

Or if possible some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df_final['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df_final['A'].str[:-1], errors='coerce')
```

And then:

```
df_final['Difference vs category'] = df_final.B.astype(float) - df_final.A
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael)'s answer, your problem is that you're trying to index a float value. You can't do that. That is why [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) casted to string before indexing, in order to be able to select a specific number. You can do the test yourself, how you can't index a float:

```py
45.0[0]
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", 
    line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-ef6abffd22f7>", line 1, in <module>
    45.0[0]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Thanks for the note, I understand it now. Whenever I want to shorten an int I would turn it to `str` and then use `astype(int/float)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Pandas, but the variable `df_final['A']` seems to be a float and you cant subscriptable a float.
Try to cast `df_final['A']` into a string and then subscript it.
If I am right that should work:

```
df_final['A'] = float(str(df_final['A']).apply(lambda x: x[:-1]))
```